# mongoid `group by` query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

In my rails application, there are two mongoid models which have a one-to-many relationship. I'm able to pick a selection of milestone ids and find all the **Steps** that belong to each **milestone**, but I need to group these steps or only return the steps from the latest milestone Steps if there are multiple. Milestones are order by position and Duplicate steps have the same **step_id**

```
ids = Milestones.where({'position' => { '$lte' => position }}).pluck(:id)
@steps= Steps.any_of({milestone_id: {"$in" => ids}, order_by: { milestone_id: ids }})
```